# ascii codec error is showing while running python3 code via apche wsgi

Tags: python-3.x, apache, ascii, wsgi

**Objective**: Insert a Japanese text to a .ini file

**Steps:**

1. Python version used 3.6 and used Flask framework
2. The library used for writing config file is Configparser

**Issue:**

When I try running the code via the "flask run" command, there are no issues. The Japanese text is inserted to ini file correctly
But when I try running the same code via apache(wsgi) I am getting the following error
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 17-23: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Never interact with text files without explicitly specifying the encoding.**

Sadly, even Python's [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) neglects to obey this simple rule.

```
import configparser

config_path = 'your_file.ini'
config = configparser.ConfigParser()

with open(config_path, encoding='utf8') as fp:
    config.read_file(fp)


with open(config_path, 'w', encoding='utf8') as fp:
    config.write(fp)
```

`utf8` is a reasonable choice for storing Unicode characters, pick a different encoding if you have a preference.

Japanese characters consume up to five bytes per character in UTF-8, picking `utf16` (always two bytes per character) can result in smaller `ini` files, but there is no functional difference.